# bash- remove \n every three lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How can I remove newline delimiter from every three lines.
Example:

input:

```
1
name
John
2
family 
Grady
3
Tel
123456
```

output:

```
1
name John
2
family Grady
3
Tel 123456
```

Comment: are you sure that your input sample after `2` is consistent? An alternate solution might be to remove all `\n` that come after a `:`.

Comment: sorry! I'm a little sleepy:D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'n;N;s/\n//' file
```

to replace the newline with a space use:

```
sed 'n:N;s/\n/ /' file
```

as an alternative use paste:

```
paste -sd'\n \n' file
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on `n;N` part?

Comment: @AvinashRaj the question says `bash- remove \n every three lines` it does not say replace `\n` with a space.

Comment: @MandarShinde see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Common-Commands) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all those lines you want joined with the next one end with `:` (your *original* question):

```
1
name:
John
2
family: Grady
3
Tel:
123456
```

You can use `sed` for this, with:

```
sed ':a;/:$/{N;s/\n//;ba}'
```

The `a` is a branch label. The pattern `:$` (colon at end of line) is detected and, if found, `N` appends the next line to the current one, the newline between them is removed with the `s/\n//` substitution command, and it branches back to label `a` with the `ba` command.

---

For your *edited* question where you just want to combine the second and third line of each three-line group regardless of content:

```
1
name
John
2
family 
Grady
3
Tel
123456
```

Use:

```
sed '{n;N;s/\n/ /}'
```

In that command sequence, `n` will output the first line in the group and replace it with the second one. Then `N` will append the third line to that second one and `s/\n/ /` will change the newline between them into a space before finally outputting the combined two-three line.

Then it goes onto the next group of three and does the same thing.

---

Both those commands will generate the desired output for their respective inputs.

Comment: If there were four words like `1    SOMETHING    name    John` and we're intended to do the same thing with them, how could we use `n` and `N`?

Comment: @Mandar, you should ask a _different_ question since it'll get more exposure than one hidden away in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'NR%3==2{printf "%s ",$0;next}{print $0}' input.txt
```

Output:

```
1
name John
2
family Grady
3
Tel 123456
```

Comment: Instead of `$0" "`, it's safer to use: `"%s ", $0`.

Comment: Slightly shorter `awk 'x=NR%3==2{printf "%s ",$0}!x'`

Comment: @confused00: If your input string contains a format specifier you will have problems; i.e. `printf()` will assume it has more arguments than it should.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in Perl,

```
$ perl -pe 's/\n/ /g if $. % 3 == 2' file
1
name John
2
family Grady
3
Tel 123456
```

Answer (score 2):

One way using AWK:

```
awk '{ printf "%s%s", $0, (NR%3==2 ? FS : RS) }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution, in Bash:

```
while read line
do
  if [[ $line = *: ]]
  then
    echo -n $line
  else
    echo $line
  fi
done < input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Unix way:

```
$ paste -sd'\n \n' input
```

Output:

```
1
name John
2
family Grady
3
Tel 123456
```